# To concatenate a string with cmp.getreference("v.name")

Tags: javascript, aura

I am trying to concatenate a string with cmp.getReference, but after concatenating it the output I am getting is very different: SecurePropertyReferenceValue: {!v.varName} { key: {"namespace":"namespace"} }.
This is the component in JS:

```
{ type: 'lightning:input', attribute: {
                    name: "fieldName",
                    label: "Label",
                    value: cmp.getReference('v.records.fieldName'),
                    required: "true",
                } } ,

What I tried:
{ type: 'lightning:input', attribute: {
                    name: "fieldName",
                    label: "Label",
                    value: cmp.getReference('v.records.fieldName')+cmp.get('v.newField'),
                    required: "true",
                } } ,

{ type: 'lightning:input', attribute: {
                    name: "fieldName",
                    label: "Label",
                    value: cmp.getReference('v.records.fieldName')+"string name",
                    required: "true",
                } } ,
```

I even tried something just like this:

```
{ type: 'lightning:input', attribute: {
                    name: "fieldName",
                    label: "Label",
                    default: "some String",
                    value: cmp.getReference('v.records.fieldName')+"string name",
                    required: "true",
                } } ,
```

But is doesn't pre-populate any default value in the input field

but it gives me this output "SecurePropertyReferenceValue: {!v.varName} { key: {"namespace":"namespace"} }", I have tried other ways also but sometimes it only fetch this "cmp.getReference('v.records.fieldName')" value and sometimes it does not fetch any value in the field.

Comment: Have you tried using just `get` instead?

Comment: Yes, it is not fetching the value in real time. cmp.get("v.someVar")+cmp.get("v.someVar2"), works but in getReference I dont know why it is not concatenating.

Comment: Also my component fetches real time value and shows on the field after committing in the database so "value: cmp.getReference('v.records.fieldName')" this is working while I tried using like this value: cmp.get('v.records.fieldName') it didn't work

Comment: The issue is resolved, as I didn't concatenate here but I concatenated there where the value of "record" array was initializing and append my string